# Indexing Heirarchial Data with Python

Tags: python, sorting, indexing, hierarchical-data

I am looking for a more pythonic way or better practice to simplify filtering data. Basically, I have class-structured data, and I want to select and group attributes. Is there a good way to do this without flattening to a tabular format?

Example:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Square:
    def __init__(self,origin,length,rotation,color):
        self.origin = origin
        self.length = length
        ...


#populated with all squares
square_list = get_squares()

#create x,y map of all squares
XYindex = defaultdict(list)
for square in square_list:
    XYindex[str(square.origin.x)+','+str(square.origin.y)].append(square)


colorindex = defaultdict(list)
for square in square_list:
    colorindex[str(square.color)].append(square)

#find black squares at 0,0
result = []
for square in colorindex['black']:
    if square in XYindex['0,0']:
        result.append(square)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use list comprehension like this:

```
result = [square for square in colorindex['black'] if square in XYindex['0,0']]
```

list comprehension is simple way to filter data when the logic is not complicated.